# Jmeter hangs even if resources avaliable

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

Hi I am using Jmeter to 20 parallel HTTP request from (20 treads each threads one request and 1 iteration). 

Each request POST JSON of almost 2mb.

I have given Jmeter heap of 30gb still jmeter threads got stuck and no response.
running jmeter in non-gui mode.

Test server is working fine.

any help what could be the issue ?

LoadGenerator system:
jmeter version : 4
OS 64bit
Windows server 2016
RAM 128GB
CPU Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2673 v3 @2.40GHZ

Comment: are you getting the issue in non-gui mode as well

Answer (score 0):

JMeter does not need 30 gb Heap to run your use case, it is even worse to do that as you'll face long GC pauses.

So reduce Heap to 4Gb and add on Http Request Defaults element:

- Connect Timeout to 5000
- Read Timeout  to 30000

And see if it still hangs.

If it still hangs double check that you're respecting those best-practices:

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/
- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

If it still hangs then make a Thread Dump and add it to your question.

Comment: It was hanging at 4gb heap so I allocated 30gb heap. I will attach the thread dump

Comment: This problem was only occurring with windows system, Jmeter is working fine in ubuntu. Now it is working fine with 4gb heap also.

Comment: don't know why jmeter keep waiting for the response in windows server even though response was sent by the server. However everything is working fine with ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was because generting the HTML report in the same command won't work for a lot of concurrent users. What I ended up doing is to first generate a CSV report and then generate a html report in a second command:

```
java -Xms3048m -Xmx3048m -jar ../../programas/apache-jmeter-5.5/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t  $PWD/tests/mono_user.jmx -l results.csv
java -Xms3048m -Xmx3048m -jar ../../programas/apache-jmeter-5.5/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -g results.csv -o results
```